# Binding free functions as class member functions

Tags: c++

I've tried to *bind* free functions as class member functions, and it works (see code bellow). But I'm puzzled how it works and have some questions.

Questions:

1. Calling the `obj_A.func_A()` is the same as calling `func_X()` directly? Is a pointer created internally in the first approach ?
2. Is there an additional overhead by calling these *methods* via `obj_A` ?
3. Are `Class_A::func_A / B` really member function? It behaves like a static ones, because it hasn't access to `Class_A` members...
4. Is this a strange design pattern? Any suggestions to improve it?

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// define some (reference to) functions signatures types
using func_A_t = int (&)(const string &);
using func_B_t = double (&)(int, int);

// class that has two "methods" (func_A, func_B) whose definition come externally
class Class_A {
public:
    string name;
    
    // function members as references?
    func_A_t& func_A;
    func_B_t& func_B;

    Class_A(string arg_name, func_A_t& arg_func_A, func_B_t& arg_func_B):
        name{arg_name},
        func_A{arg_func_A},
        func_B{arg_func_B}
    {
    }
};

// external 'free' function
int func_X(const string& s) {
    return s.size();
}

// external 'free' function
double func_Y(int a, int b) {
    return 1.75 * a * b;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    // contruct obj_A, binding the free functions (func_X, func_Y) as Class_A member functions
    Class_A obj_A{"crazy test", func_X, func_Y};
    
    int r1 = obj_A.func_A("Hello");
    cout << "r1=" << r1 << "\n";

    double r2 = obj_A.func_B(5, 7);
    cout << "r2=" << r2 << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Calling the `obj_A.func_A()` is the same as calling `func_X()` directly?

Yes

> Is a pointer created internally in the first approach?

Yes (assuming you mean "in the constructor")

> Is there an additional overhead by calling these methods via `obj_A`?

Yes. An additional level of indirection is possible, although the compiler may optimize this away depending on how you use it.

> Are `Class_A::func_A` / B really member function?

No, they are member *variables* that happen to be function pointers

> Is this a strange design pattern?

That is subjective, but I think not. It is used a lot in *dependency injection* architectures. For example, injecting details of how to obtain a handle to a database.

> Any suggestions to improve it?

We'd need a pretty specific use case to provide guidance. StackOverflow may not be the best place for that discussion. For now, it's not typical to expose the injected dependency publicly. You may consider a proxy pattern where you can call-through to the function instead. This allows you more flexibility.